# Setting up a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with Tomcat 7.0

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ide

I am having issues properly setting up a dynamic web project in Eclipse [Juno] using Apache Tomcat 7.0. I have JRE and JDK 1.7 installed. These are the steps that I have taken:

1. Tomcat files extracted to my `C:\Program Files\` directory.
2. New > Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with target runtime [Apache Tomcat v7.0] and dynamic web module version [2.5].
3. Created an `index.jsp` file in `WebContent > WEB-INF`.
4. In Tomcat properties, set `Server Location` as `Use Tomcat installation`.
5. Set the `Deploy path` as my Tomcat webapps location. In this case, `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps`.
6. Right-click project folder > Run As > Run On Server > Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

This results in a 404 error when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName`, but `http://localhost:8080` successfully shows the Tomcat welcome page.

Are there any steps in between that I may be missing or any configuration options that I've neglected to adjust? I have another web project in my workspace from a while back that runs fine, but I've been unable to create a new dynamic web project successfully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't put the `index.jsp` in `WEB-INF`.  Put it in `WebContent`.